# How to refresh a method of Child Component when I press Button on Parent Component in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a submit button with a select option in a form field in Parent Component Now, when User changes the select option it will take that value and execute a method/function in the child component.
Whenever he changes I want to update child function automatically.

```html
<select>
  <option value="www.google.com">google</option>
  <option value="www.facebook.com">facebook</option>
  <option value="www.twitter.com">twitter</option>
 
</select>

<button> Submit </button>
```

Now when Someone press the submit button it will execute a function on Child component

```js
export default {
  name: 'child',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Child',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething: function (url) {
     var newurl = url;
      
    }
    }
}
```

So, when press button will be pressed that time **doSomething** method will execute with the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global event bus` mechanism for parent-children communication. Here's an article which goes in depth on how you should implement this.

https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very precise.

Do you only want to trigger a child component method from parent ?
In such a case, from your parent component, give a ref to your child component, then call the child component method this way :

```
this.$refs[child-component-ref].doSomething()
```

If you need to pass a value to the child method from your parent select element, add this value to your method call :

```
this.$refs[child-component-ref].doSomething(my select value)
```